# Difficulty upgrading custom templated dialogs from dojo 1.5 to 1.7.3 or 1.8.0

Tags: dojo

I am working on upgrading a web app from dojo 1.5 to 1.8 (or 1.7.3). This app has several custom templated widgets that inherit from dijit.Dialog. I am finding that these don't render correctly at all. For an example, see http://jsfiddle.net/tinyels/XhrWF/1/

If you set it to dojo 1.5 or 1.6 it lays out correctly. In 1.7, it won't even `show()`. In 1.8, various attachpoints are missing and buttons don't work.  Inspecting it in a debugger shows that it only has the some attachpoints (titleBar, titleNode, closeButtonNode, closeText, containerNode, gridContainer) and is missing several such as btnGo.

What changes do I need to make to the widget (or it's template) to get it to work in newer versions of Dojo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that `widgetsInTemplate` does not work anymore in Dojo 1.7+. Your template is not parsed at all. You can manually call `dojo.parser.parse(this.containerNode)` (e.g. in `postCreate`), but you will be missing `dojoAttachPoint` and `dojoAttachEvent` generated references.

The Dojo 1.7+ way of having widgets in a template is to subclass `dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin`, in your case:

```
dojo.require("dijit._WidgetsInTemplateMixin");

dojo.declare("imed.widgets.DapDialog", [dijit.Dialog, dijit._WidgetsInTemplateMixin], {});
```

and all should work as before. Try it at jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/UEXmF/